# Не работает конструкция if else в Python

Tags: python

Итак, есть такая конструкция if else:

```
if int(first_player):
    random_number = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(random_number)
else:
    print('Вы ввели некорректные данные')
```

Ну т.е. условие по моей логике должно проверять, является ли вводимый текст цифрой и можно ли его преобразовать в них.
На деле я получаю эту ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/untitled/lesson5.py", line 10, in <module>
    if int(first_player) == True:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ва'
```

Почему он просто не следует инструкции else, когда видит, что строку нельзя преобразовать в цифры? Если не так, то каким образом следует проверять тип вводимых значений?

```
IDE - Pycharm
Python - 3.8
```

Comment: `string.isdigit()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конструкция `if..else` работает. Не работает конверсия текста в число. Точнее, завершается с ошибкой. Функция `int()` не проверяет тип данных, а делает из входного аргумента целое число. Если такое невозможно, то выполнение программы останавливается с ошибкой.

Что же делать?

В зависимости от задачи можно использовать разные варианты.

Например, проверять тип данных:

```
if type(x) == int:
    print("целое число")
```

Не подходит, если x получен вводом данных с клавиатуры. Для подобной ситуации обычно  применяют конструкцию `try..except`:

```
try:
    y = int(x)
    print("получилось")
except ValueError:
    print("не получилось")
```

В этом случае, если конвертация x в целое число невозможна (например, х = "ва"), то ошибка будет отловлена блоком `except` и будет выполнен код, содержащийся в этом блоке.

PS. Что происходит здесь: `if int(first_player):`

Интерпретатор пытается конвертировать `first_player` в целое число. Поскольку с "ва" это невозможно, то до `if` даже не доходит, так как программа обрывается уже на `int()`.

А теперь предположим, что переменная `first_player` равна "0". После `int("0")` у нас будет 0, а 0 это то же самое, что `False`. Поэтому если ввести 0, то будет выполнен блок `else`, несмотря на то, что конвертация в `int` была успешна.

Comment: Ваш метод рабочий, благодарю! Однако, пожалуй, я воспользуюсь методом, предложенным   S. Nick - `string.isdigit()`, ибо его можно использовать в рамках конструкции  if else. Постараюсь изучить и найти применение вашей конструкции в том числе. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Хороший и развернутый ответ, плюсик вам поставил. Но как видно человеку еще рано в обработку ошибок, это для него слишком сложно, но обещает в дальнейшем освоить - и это не может не радовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

first_player = input(" enter > ")
if first_player.isdigit():
    first_player = int(first_player)
    random_number = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(random_number)
else:
    print('Вы ввели некорректные данные')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]